# Windows 7 не видит Raspberry pi pico

Tags: windows-7, raspberry-pi

У меня возникла проблема с тем, что Windows 7 x32 не определяет Raspberry pi pico как com порт, а как неизвестное устройство. Я устанавливал MicroPython на него, перезагружал. Но всё тщетно.